# How can I utilize jq to filter out entries with value over 0?

Tags: jq, github-cli

I have the results of a Github Commandline call with the following JSON format:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "repository-1",
    "pullRequests": {
      "totalCount": 129
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "repository-2",
    "pullRequests": {
      "totalCount": 1143
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "repository-3",
    "pullRequests": {
      "totalCount": 78
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "repository-4",
    "pullRequests": {
      "totalCount": 0
    }
  }
]
```

This is the output of `gh repo list ORG-REPO --json pullRequests,name`

I have many many more repositories in there and my goal is to get a list of all repositories that have 0 pull requests so that I can act on those (archive).

How can I do this utilizing `jq`?

I've tried:

```
.[].pullRequests.totalCount -> This gives me the numeric value of each record
.[].pullRequests.totalCount,.[].name -> This gives me the list from above and then the list of repository names
```

How can I filter the list of repositories to only show the repository name where `pullRequests.totalCount = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `select` to filter by criteria, here `.pullRequests.totalCount == 0`, and `map` that onto the input array:

```bash
jq 'map(select(.pullRequests.totalCount == 0))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "repository-4",
    "pullRequests": {
      "totalCount": 0
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i2FGstjdlgA)

If you are only interested in the names, add that to the mapping:

```bash
jq 'map(select(.pullRequests.totalCount == 0).name)'
```

```json
[
  "repository-4"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8LOeYm-xTIp)

If you want the names as a list of newline-separated raw texts rather than a JSON array of strings, iterate over the elements and use the `--raw-output` or `-r` for the output:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | select(.pullRequests.totalCount == 0).name'
```

```json
repository-4
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/E7d9nfwM9y2)